# before_print macro check required fields are not blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro to execute a before_print check. There are certain fields that must be populated in order for the user to print the template.  The macro works fine but the message box will appear as many times as there is a blank field.  Meaning if 3 of the 5 fields are blank then the message box will appear (3) times which means the user will have to close each message box.

Question:  I would like to see what I would need to modify so that the message box only appears once regardless of how many of the required fields are left blank.  All I care about is if any of the fields are blank to show the message box and cancel the print job.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Template" Then

Dim jRange As Range
Set jRange = Sheets("Template").Range("C4,C5,B9,B10,B11")


For Each cell In jRange

    If cell.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Cannot leave Invoice Number, Invoice Date or Vendor Name blank."), vbCritical
        Cancel = True

    End If
Next


End If


End Sub
```

Revised macro after assistance:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Template" Then

Dim jRange As Range
Set jRange = Sheets("Template").Range("C4,C5,B9,B8,B10")


Dim ReqFields As Boolean

For Each cell In jRange

    If cell.Value = "" Then
        ReqFields = True

    End If
Next

If ReqFields Then

MsgBox ("Cannot leave Invoice Number, Invoice Date or Vendor Name blank."), vbCritical
        Cancel = True
End If

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of showing a MsgBox each time through the loop, set a Boolean variable to "True".  After the loop, if the Boolean is true, then you know that there was at least one field blank.  At that point, show your error message and set "Cancel = True".

Comment: Thanks for the insight!  I modified it in this manner and it works now whereby the message box only appears once when it executs the before_print check on the required fields.

Comment: Very cool! And thanks for marking my answer as The Answer. :)